# Add a module (not package) to buildout for Plone

Tags: plone, buildout

Is there a way to add a simple module (e.g. mymodule.py) which resides in the src/ directory to buildout for Plone 4? To be more specific, I have a former module I used as an ExternalMethod in Plone 2.5, and I'm trying to use it in Plone 4 without creating a package or using paster and creating an egg. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zope2instance
You can just the extra_paths option. That would allow it to be imported from other code.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

- you could put it in a skin layer and use it with the Aquisition. But,
  if you used to use it as an ExternalMethod, I suppose it needs to be
  executed by a not-restricted python
- make a package using the paster template "plone" for a basic package.
- put it into `/<buildout-root>/parts/instance/Extensions` or `/<buildout-root>/parts/client1/Extensions`

You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031070/external-methods-for-plone-zope).

**edit**: it turns out that the last option is not suitable...so you have only 2 options + the one from @djay

Comment: Just a note on that last option: anything in the "parts/" directory tree can be eliminated or changed whenever you run buildout. So, it's wise to never maintain things there directly.